# Why does the Search host service require the core service and content manager

Tags: core-service, content-manager, search

I'm looking at the [documentation about installing search on a dedicated machine](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A3AED55C-4AA3-46DF-8C1C-4EEF25D12E1E). There it says: "You can install a separate Search Host service on a dedicated machine by running the Content Manager installer. The Search Host service requires the Core Service and Content Manager core to run".

My understanding so far is that the Search Host runs an instance of Solr, which presumably can communicate with everything else via web services. Why then does it need the core service and content manager?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Tridion Search Host service is indeed nothing more than Tomcat in disguise. It hosts the Tridion SOLR search index. It doesn't depend on Content Manager and/or Core Service.

The Tridion Search Indexer service is the one monitoring the CM search queue, obtaining the data to be indexed from CM (normally on the same machine) and sending it to the SOLR search index.

If the documentation states that the Search Host requires CM, that's a mistake. The Search Indexer does.

Comment: Thanks for answering this, Rick. Often our understanding of the architecture is build up from little hints in the documentation. (With the best will in the world, the documentation guys are often focussed on how to rather than why.) If the dependency had been real, I'd have had to start all over again.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess its hardcoded to only be able to access the content it has to index on the localhost - it needs these webservices on the same machine.

Comment: Hi Rogier... I'm specifically talking about the Search Host, and not the Search Indexer. Are you saying that the search host reads the Tridion item? I had imagined that the indexer would do that.

Comment: @DominicCronin I think the Search Indexer indeed is just a queueing mechanism (passing URIs) and the Search Host reads the Tridion item, using the Core Service, most likely via the net.tcp binding on localhost.

Comment: @BartKoopman - then what's the point of the Search Indexer? Why would you want or need two distinct services?

Comment: @DominicCronin I don't know